# [C#]Doesn't insert in DB, does give a executenonquery of 1

Tags: c#, sql, error-handling, insert

I am busy with a project in which I have to insert some data in a compact SQL db file which is created in Visual Studio 2010 express. Every check I do says the insert is being done properly, only one drawback, everytime I check the database no data is inserted.
I tried:

Checking the command.executenonquery() result

I tried and catched.

I did a direct SQL insert and that worked.

I checked the Connectionstate.

So I am out of Ideas, I hope you guys can help.

Oh, and the code might be of use:

```
    private void butAddOilBlend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ConnectToDB Connection = new ConnectToDB();
        try
        {
            Connection.Connect.Open();

            string SQLCommand = "INSERT INTO OilBlendsTable(oilblendsName, oilblendsDescription) VALUES(@OilBlendsName, @OilBlendsDescription)";

            using (SqlCeCommand Command = new SqlCeCommand(SQLCommand, Connection.Connect))
            {
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OilBlendsName", tbNameOilBlend.Text);
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OilBlendsDescription", tbOilBlendDescription.Text);

                Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                int AffectedRows = Command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                MessageBox.Show(AffectedRows.ToString());
            }

            lblFinalWord.Text = "You just added a new blend named: " + tbNameOilBlend.Text;
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            Connection.Connect.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does your connection string contain `AttachDbFilename` ?

Comment: Your code is correct ( excluding the double call to ExecuteNonQuery, but I think that this is a leftover of your tries). Are you sure that you are checking the exact database used by the insert? Do you have the database file listed in your projects files with the property Copy to Destination Directory set to Copy Always and your connection string points to a |DataDirectory|?

Comment: and please have a look at IDisposable and the using statement and connection pooling.

Comment: I just set the Cop to Destination to Copy Always, I'll place a copy of my conn string here:

Data Source=|DataDirectory|\OilDB.sdf;Password=(Secret);Persist Security Info=True

I believe it's okay the way it is.. And my connectionstring doesn't contain AttachDbFilename, I never heard of it. I'll google it right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Copy Always` means that every time you start to debug your application a fresh copy of the SDF file is copied from the `Project Directory` to the `DataDirectory` overwriting the file already there.

The `DataDirectory` in a winforms app is BIN\DEBUG.
Your inserts are going into that database (BIN\DEBUG\OilDB.sdf).
At the next run these inserts are lost.
You should use `Copy If Newer`

[Where is the |DataDirectory|](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/dc31ea59-5718-49b6-9f1f-7039da425296/)
[Visual Studio - File Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Here I am supposing that you check the missing data looking at the file stored in the project directory through a connection defined in the Server Explorer Window. Check its connection string

Comment: Glad for you, Was it the Server Explorer connection?